# can i declare a class with generic form and then cast the subclasses to the type that is declared generic in java

Tags: java, generics, subclass

ok, here is what I mean.
I have a class that is declared like

```
public abstract class Agent<E extends Human> extends SuperAgent<E>{
}
```

and I have

```
public class Soldier extends Agent<Platoon>
```

and

```
public class Platoon extends Human
```

is there a way to cast Human to Soldier? or use the method `instanceof` for these two types? or even have a `Human` parameter in `Soldier`?

Comment: `SuperAgent` is the parent of `Agent`, and `SuperAgent` has no relation with `Human`@MaximShoustin

Comment: Then you can't cast `Human` to `Soldier`.

Comment: You're missing something.  `public class Soldier extends Agent<??what??>` what type specializes `Agent`?  Presumably it's `public class Soldier extends Agent<Human>` but then a `Soldier` will contain a `Human`, not _be_ a human.  You need to show better examples of how you use this code.  Until then it's not really clear what you're asking.

Comment: I edited the code in the question @JimGarrison, so that you can see `Soldier` contains a child of `Human` (`Platoon`)

Comment: Platoon does not have an "is-a" relationship with Human. Platoon "has" (or contains) Soldiers.  Your type hierarchy is messed up, but it's not clear what you're trying to express.  Assuming `Human` is intended to model a person, you need to explain the real-world concepts represented by `Agent`, `SuperAgent`, `Soldier` and `Platoon`.  I would guess `Soldier` _is-a_ `Human`, and `Platoon` _has_ `Human`s... but I can't guess what `Agent` and `SuperAgent` are.

Comment: It's not my hierarchy :( it's a base code that I have to work on, so I am in the same stage, trying to guess what was meant to achieve here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to distinct type hierarchy:

```
SuperAgent<E> <= Agent<E extends Human> <= Soldier
Human <= Platoon
```

1. > Is there a way to cast Human to Soldier?

   They do not belong to the same hierarchy. There is no way a `Human` could be a `Soldier`.
2. > use the method instanceof for these two types?

   You can always use `instanceof` between an object and a class.
3. > or even have a Human parameter in Soldier?

   You could, but you have already fixed the parameter to be a `Platoon`. You will have to declare `Soldier` like:

   ```
   public class Soldier<H extends Human> extends Agent<H>
   ```

I think the notion of *generics* is still confusing you, you should read [a little bit of documentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java).

Comment: Yes I really am confused with generic declaring, thanks a lot for your help. 
I thought that because `Soldier` is an `Agent`, which is kind of `Human` then it is an instance of `Human` too

Answer (score 0):

The relation is not really clear.
Human is a class,Agent is another class and soldier,too.
meanwhile Agent is a kind of Human,so do soldier.
you can declaer them like this:
Interface Human
Abstract class SuperAgent implements Human
Abstarct class Agent extends SuperAgent
Class soldier implements Human

Answer (score -1):

To cast one class to another they must be on the same inheritance tree. Then you can `upcast` or `downcast`.